# Create filter for two dynamic tables by link to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I created two dynamic tables on the same sheet.
Names are : "Tableau croisé dynamique1" and "Tableau croisé dynamique4"

I would like to use a cell reference to filter the two tables.

I found code for one table. I tried to duplicate it and change the variable.

The objective is to have the filters of the tables working the same.
If I filter for "week 26" both tables should show "week 26" data.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 
    Dim xPTable As PivotTable
    Dim xPFile As PivotField
    Dim xStr As String
    
    Dim xPTable4 As PivotTable
    Dim xPFile4 As PivotField
    Dim xStr4 As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set xPTable4 = Worksheets("Resumen_ventas").PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique4")
    Set xPFile4 = xPTable.PivotFields("SEMANA")
    
    Set xPTable = Worksheets("Resumen_ventas").PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1")
    Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("SEMANA")
    
    xStr4 = Target.Text
    
    xStr = Target.Text
    xPFile.ClearAllFilters
    xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr
  
    xPFile4.ClearAllFilters
    xPFile4.CurrentPage = xStr4
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excel screen shot here of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7WFa.jpg)

[the "SEMANA" field for each PivotTable must be visible on the sheet (drag it under "Filters" to make them PageFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeyLk.jpg)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.currentpage

You have to disable events for that, because some the ClearAllFilters() method triggers another Change event on the sheet.

```
Set xPFile4 = xPTable.PivotFields("SEMANA")
```

corrected in:

```
Set xPFile4 = xPTable4.PivotFields("SEMANA")
```

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xPTable As PivotTable
Dim xPFile As PivotField
Dim xStr As String

Dim xPTable4 As PivotTable
Dim xPFile4 As PivotField
Dim xStr4 As String

On Error Resume Next

If Intersect(Target, Range("B3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set Target2 = Range("B4")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set xPTable4 = Worksheets("Resumen_ventas").PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique4")
Set xPFile4 = xPTable4.PivotFields("SEMANA")

xStr4 = Target2.Text
Application.EnableEvents = False
    xPFile4.ClearAllFilters
Application.EnableEvents = True
xPFile4.CurrentPage = xStr4

Set xPTable = Worksheets("Resumen_ventas").PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique1")
Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("SEMANA")

xStr = Target2.Text
Application.EnableEvents = False
    xPFile.ClearAllFilters
Application.EnableEvents = True
xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @cedcr4 I have change the code with your but it's not as expected. the filter do nothing. what the Set Target2 = Range("B4") doing as my cell ("B4") is empty ? but changing only this line "Set xPFile4 = xPTable4.PivotFields("SEMANA")"   in my code work like a charm